# Image on a button with drawing a circle

Tags: swift, drawimage

I have button on which I show an image. The Image (image in a circle as png with transparent color outside of the circle) is in a circle and the Button is transparent. When I draw the button on the screen I can see only the circeled button. 
This works fine so far.

Now I would like to draw a black circle around the Image at runtime.
Any hints on how to do that ?

my function creating the button:

```
  func draw_button(sImage:String,X:CGFloat,Y:CGFloat, iTag:Int){

        // Back Button
        var sImagename=sImage;
        var fButtonx:CGFloat=X;
        var fButtony:CGFloat=Y;

        var thebutton=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(fButtonx, fButtony, iButtonSize, iButtonSize));
        thebutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonActionBotton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        thebutton.tag = iTag;
        var image = UIImage(named: sImagename);


        thebutton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        var transparent:UIColor=UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.0);
        thebutton.backgroundColor=transparent;
        thebutton.layer.backgroundColor=transparent.CGColor;
        self.view.addSubview(backButton);


    }
```

Any hints on how I could do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subview situated just under button. 
Set its background to black colour and use its layer cornerRadius property to achieve circle shape.

```
let circleSubview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(fButtonx, fButtony, iButtonSize, iButtonSize);
circleSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
circleSubview.layer.cornerRadius = //whatever you need; I believe, it should be something around 10.0 or more - try it yourself


//after backButton added to view hierarchy 
self.view.insertSubview(view: circleSubview, belowSubview : backButton)
```

Some advices - you don't need your views to be variables. Use `let` instead `var`. And you have class function `UIColor.clearColor()` instead of creating transparent colour by yourself.

Comment: Perfect answer. So easy. And also thank you for the good hint regarding clearing the color.